# How do i protect string in text box?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have problem with text box named "txtPrice". I want to protect this text box from a string. If we input one string it will show message that I wrote. But if I input, for example "12r", it doesn't do anything.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As Long
i = Asc(txtPrice)
If i < 48 or i> 57 then    'ascii number
     MsgBox "Error"
End If
```

Comment: Please explain what values are acceptable for `txtPrice`.  Must it include only digits?  Is Null allowed?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you looking for? Under properties you can specify an input mask.

You can try `If Not IsNumeric(txtPrice)` if you're looking for a number.

If you don't want any letters, try this:

```
Dim intPos As Integer

For intPos = 1 To Len(txtPrice)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(txtPrice, intPos, 1))
        Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
            IsLetter = True
        Case Else
            IsLetter = False
    End Select
    If IsLetter Then Exit For
Next intPos

If IsLetter Then
    MsgBox "Error"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this within the properties of the text box field using validation rules:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Restrict-data-input-by-using-validation-rules-b91c6b15-bcd3-42c1-90bf-e3a0272e988d

You can restrict data entry in this way. For instance you could enter >=0 in the validation rules property and then "Please enter numbers only" in the validation text property. I have used both methods (vba as previous answer) and access validation rules and both work well.